# How to transcribe Whisper Open AI transcription for large video files larger than 25mb using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I'm using whisper to transcribe audio in my webapp, how should I handle audio files greater than 25 mb. I've already tried using lamejs for compression but it didn't work. So either compression or splitting the audio in parts before sending it to whisper. Help me with the code or whatever worked for you!